# Browserify inserts @reactivex/rxjs to the bundle

Tags: angularjs, browserify, browserify-shim

I use the `ng-forward` library with `browserify`, and browserify inserts `@reactivex/rxjs` to the bundle. How to prevent this? I have tried `browserify-shim`, but it does not work. Config was:

```
{
    "browserify-shim": {
        "rxjs": "global:Rx"
    }
}
```